# How to use the multireader API correctly in Lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have several indexes, but wanted to know which way of using is correct.

```
IndexReader r1= IndexReader.open(...)
IndexReader r2= IndexReader.open(...)
MultiReader mr= new MultiReader(r1,r2)
```

1)

```
IndexSearcher s = new IndexSearcher(mr);
```

2)

```
IndexSearcher s = new IndexSearcher(mr,new IndexReader[]{r1,r2}....
```

Which one is correct?

Comment: just read the API for the latter: "WARNING: This API is experimental and might change in incompatible ways in the next release."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by Lucene API Doc you should stick to,

```java
IndexSearcher s = new IndexSearcher(mr);
```

In most versions of Lucene Library, constructor usages of IndexSearcher that accepts subreaders (additional array of IndexSearchders) are marked with warning discouraging their use,

```java
IndexSearcher s = new IndexSearcher(mr,new IndexReader[]{r1,r2}....
```

is marked with **'WARNING: This API is experimental and might change in incompatible ways in the next release.'**. I guess the reason those additional constructors options introduced was to facilitate internal Lucene Subclassing, please refer to comments on [LUCENE-1925](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1925)

- [IndexSearcher - 3.0.1](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html)
- [IndexSearcher - 3.4.0](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html)
- [IndexSearcher -
  3.5.0](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html)